# Make background of annotation box in image semi-transparent

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on adding annotations to satellite images in MATLAB. Since the color underneath each text field can vary quite a lot, I want to use a background color under the text to make it easier to see and read.

However, when I do this, a lot of the terrain gets obscured. I though of trying to make the background color for each text box semi transparent, but hit a dead end trying to come up with a solution.

Any ideas? I was hoping for some UI-element where I could just set the 'facealpha' to maybe 0.5. I also need the text to support being rotated (as can be seen in the examples below).

Below is some example code and the resulting image. The workspace with the satellite data can also be found in the link:
[Example workspace](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D775999_2_6422473093)

```
figure(1);clf
imagesc(xx,yy,Map);

hold on
plot(xInspection,yInspection,'g.-')

% # Two ways of making a rotated text annotation. 
% # Cant make background semi-transparent
testAnno= annotation('textarrow',[0.5 0.5],[0.5 0.5], ...
                'string','textarrow annotation', ...
                'HeadStyle','none','LineStyle', 'none',...
                'TextRotation',asin(directionVec(1))*180/pi,...
                'TextBackgroundColor',[0.7 0.7 0.7]);

testText = text(mean(xInspection),mean(yInspection),'text annotation', ...
        'rotation',asin(directionVec(1))*180/pi, ...
        'HorizontalAlignment','right', ...
        'color',[0 0 0], ...
        'backgroundcolor',[0.7 0.7 0.7], ...
        'fontsize',8);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like either `annotation` or `text` return HgObjects that have `BackgroundAlpha` properties (they might exist but I wasn't able to find them using [`getundoc`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32934-getundoc-get-undocumented-object-properties) or by trying various different hacks).

I was able to get something working by drawing the background myself. Here is a simple proof of concept:

```
f = figure;
tObj = text(.5, .5, 'text object', 'FontSize', 20);
set(gca,'XLimMode', 'manual', 'YLimMode', 'manual'); % prevent the axes from resizing automatically
p = get(tObj, 'Extent'); %Get the outer position of the text

% now create a  patch around the text object
pObj = patch([p(1) p(1) p(1)+p(3) p(1)+p(3)], [p(2) p(2)+p(4) p(2)+p(4) p(2)], 'r');
uistack(tObj, 'top'); % put the text object on top of the patch object

set(pObj , 'FaceAlpha', .2); % set the alpha of the patch face to .2

%Rotate the objects
set(tObj, 'Rotation', 20);
rotate(pObj, [0 0 1], 20);
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems promising, although the patch and text object are placed in slightly different places after rotating them. I suspect they might be using different pivot-points.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid the only way you can do this is by not setting any color to your annotations, and then placing a `patch` in the background of each annotation. So something like this:

```
% Use completely transparent annotations
hA = annotation('textarrow', ..., 'TextBackgroundColor', 'none')

% Place a transparent patch exactly in the background of your annotation
hP = patch(X, Y, 'white', 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', 'white', ...
    'alpha', 0.3)

% Ensure that your annotation is on top
uistack(hA, 'top')
```

But of course the big problem is to determine the correct coordinates of the patch (`X` and `Y`). Rotating is easy by simply multiplying your coordinates by a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). However, finding the length and height of the patch and its central location is not that easy. You might be able to find some useful functions for this at Matlab central...