# How does one add an outline to text in Matlab?

Tags: string, image, matlab, annotations, transparency

I have added a [`textbox`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotationtextboxproperties.html) [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) to an [`image`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html), but it is difficult to read the text if I don't use a background. If I do use a background, I obscure the image. I have examined one possible solution which is inelegant:

- Add transparency to the annotation background. This is not built-in and requires a [kluge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232341/make-background-of-annotation-box-in-image-semi-transparent).

One possible alternative which I would like to try is to add an outline to the text. Anyone know how to do that?

**EDIT**

I should have been more specific by what I had meant by "add an outline to the text". I meant Microsoft Word's definition of an outline.

[image: Image of a text outline.]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you don't just want a text box. I am not sure how to fix the text but based on the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729369/matlab-textbox-alpha-does-not-adjust-all-background-color), you can set the box transparency.

```
plot(sin(rand(10)))
a = annotation('textbox', [0.5 0.5 0.1 0.1], 'String', 'Some Random Text');
b = annotation('textbox', get(a,'Position'));
set(b, 'BackgroundColor', [0 0.5 0]);
set(b, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
uistack(a,'top')
```

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I believe you missed this part of the question: "If I do use a background, I obscure the image." In the context of my problem, the text will be quite large compared to the image, so I cannot use an opaque background.

Comment: @PeterD There you go, i have edited to do exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the `textborder` function on MATLAB file exchange attempts to solve this problem.
http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27383-textborder-higher-contrast-text-using-a-1-pixel-thick-border