# Matlab textbox alpha does not adjust all background color

Tags: matlab, textbox, transparency

I have a very simple script that plots some random stuff and puts a `textbox` with background color. I am attempting to change the transparency of the background so that the plot shows through.

I have the following code:

```
x = rand(10);
plot(sin(x))
a = annotation('textbox', [0.5 0.5 0.1 0.1], 'String', 'Some Random Text');
set(a, 'BackgroundColor', [.7 .9 .7]);
set(a, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
```

And it results in an image like this:

[image]

So obviously the transparency has worked because part of the background colour is transparent.

**Why is all of it not transparent? Have I done something wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Mathworks confirmed that it probably is a bug which might be fixed in 2014b (to be released in July 2014). A temporary workaround is:

```
plot(sin(rand(10)))
a = annotation('textbox', [0.5 0.5 0.1 0.1], 'String', 'Some Random Text');
b = annotation('textbox', get(a,'Position'));
set(b, 'BackgroundColor', [0 0.5 0]);
set(b, 'FaceAlpha', 1);
uistack(a,'top')
```

One annotation for the text and below another for the background color.

---

It might be a Matlab bug actually. The documentation about [annotations](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/annotationtextboxproperties.html) says:

> FaceAlpha
>
> Scalar alpha value in range [0 1] Transparency of object background.
>   Defines the degree to which the object's background color is
>   transparent. A value of 1 (the default) makes the background opaque, a
>   value of 0 makes the background completely transparent (that is,
>   invisible). The default value is 1.

I would conclude that the whole background should be affected but I can confirm that this is not the case also here (Matlab 2012b). I might file a bug report with them.

For a temporary fix, set the backgroundcolor as bright as possible ([0.9, 0.9, 0.9] for example) then one doesn't see the effect immediately.